# Unable to deploy minimal flask app using Socket.io, Gunicorn, and eventlet

Tags: flask, gunicorn, flask-socketio, eventlet

I am attempting to deploy a Flask-Socket.io app using Gunicorn and eventlet as per the documentation: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html.

I have both Gunicorn and eventlet installed, but when I run `gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 myapp:app`, I get the following error which prints out repeatedly until I kill the process.

```
[2023-08-22 19:51:01 -0400] [57647] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 143, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in init_process
    self.run()
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 173, in run
    eventlet.sleep(1.0)
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 36, in sleep
    hub.switch()
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 313, in switch
    return self.greenlet.switch()
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 365, in run
    self.wait(sleep_time)
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/kqueue.py", line 98, in wait
    result = self._control([], self.MAX_EVENTS, seconds)
  File "/Users/alexpalacios/Documents/Projects/spotify-game/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/kqueue.py", line 39, in _control
    return self.kqueue.control(events, max_events, timeout)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Below is my code and version info for dependencies.

myapp.py:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(data):
    print('received message: ' + data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

version info:

```
Python==3.8.8
Flask==2.3.2
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.5
eventlet==0.33.3
gunicorn==21.2.0
```

The app runs fine using `python myapp.py`, but my end goal is to deploy an actual app on Render.com, which is why I want to make Gunicorn work.

The server will start up when I call `eventlet.monkey_patch()` and run the command `gunicorn -w 1 myapp:app`, and I am able to connect from Postman, however the connection is terminated after a short time and I receive this error message.
`[2023-08-22 20:10:52 -0400] [57992] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:57994) [2023-08-22 20:10:52 -0400] [57994] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 57994) [2023-08-22 20:10:53 -0400] [57992] [ERROR] Worker (pid:57994) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory? [2023-08-22 20:10:53 -0400] [58006] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 58006`

I would appreciate any advice, since the code I am working with is very simple so it seems I am missing a key concept here. Thank you!

EDIT:
I fixed the problem by deleting my virtual environment and reinstalling dependencies.

old requirements.txt

```
annotated-types==0.5.0
anyio==3.7.1
async-timeout==4.0.2
bidict==0.22.1
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
click==8.1.6
cycler==0.11.0
dnspython==2.4.2
eventlet==0.33.3
exceptiongroup==1.1.2
Flask==2.3.2
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.5
fonttools==4.40.0
greenlet==2.0.2
gunicorn==21.2.0
h11==0.14.0
httpcore==0.17.3
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.8.0
importlib-resources==6.0.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
kiwisolver==1.4.4
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
marshmallow==3.20.1
matplotlib==3.7.2
numpy==1.24.4
packaging==23.1
Pillow==10.0.0
pluggy==1.2.0
pydantic-core==2.4.0
pymongo==4.4.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
pytest==7.4.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-engineio==4.5.1
python-socketio==5.8.0
python-vlc==3.0.18122
redis==4.6.0
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.3.0
spotipy==2.23.0
tomli==2.0.1
typing-extensions==4.7.1
urllib3==2.0.4
Werkzeug==2.3.6
zipp==3.15.0
```

New requirements.txt

```
async-timeout==4.0.3
bidict==0.22.1
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2023.7.22
charset-normalizer==3.2.0
click==8.1.7
dnspython==2.4.2
eventlet==0.33.3
flask==2.3.3
Flask-Cors==4.0.0
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.5
greenlet==2.0.2
gunicorn==21.2.0
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==6.8.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
marshmallow==3.20.1
packaging==23.1
pymongo==4.5.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python-engineio==4.6.1
python-socketio==5.8.0
redis==5.0.0
requests==2.31.0
six==1.16.0
spotipy==2.23.0
urllib3==2.0.4
werkzeug==2.3.7
zipp==3.16.2
```

Comment: Using the same versions that you are using and the app.py example from the Flask-SocketIO GitHub repository I have no problem deploying with Gunicorn. The command that I used was `gunicorn -k eventlet -w 1 app:app`. This put the app on port 8000.

Comment: I was able to fix my problem by deleting my virtual environment and starting a fresh one where I reinstalled all dependencies one by one. I was not able to find which extraneous dependency caused the problem, but I've added my old requirements.txt and new requirements.txt to the original post if anyone is interested.